# RC4 using a key without nonce's or IV's

Tags: cryptanalysis, rc4

I'm researching RC4 and I am trying to recreate a condition where RC4 is crackable. However I can't quite find the article/resource I need to find the weakness for an implementation like this (python):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
f = open('key.txt')
key = f.readline().strip()

o = open('output.txt','w')
f = open('input.txt')
for line in f:
    cipher = ARC4.new(key)
    print >>o, cipher.encrypt(line).encode('hex')
```

I know the weakness is that the same key is used to encrypt the traffic, however I need a hint as to how this might impact the security of the algorithm.

Comment: Hint: what would you get if you xor two of the ciphertexts together?

Comment: The key stream?

Comment: Potentially interesting as it contains links to papers and infos related to your Q as well as some python files to play with in the “[Resources](https://www.rc4nomore.com/#resources)” section $\rightarrow$ [rc4nomore.com](https://www.rc4nomore.com/)

Comment: @Don, no, you get the xor of the two plaintexts.